# Azure data factory problem to write data from a Postgresql in private Vnet to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to retrieve data from a table located in a postgresql database hosted on azure VM. I would like to inject this data into an Azure SQL Database. I set up the self hosted integration runtime. Since the Vm hosting my DB is a linux VM, i have setup self-hosted IR on windows VM and using that I am able to connect to DB and copy the data to ABS location without any problem but when I try to copy the same data to SQL database, I am getting following error:

> ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'XXX', Database: 'XXX', User: 'XXX'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.),
>
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,**SqlErrorNumber=10060,Class=20,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=20,Number=10060,State=0**,Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. ...

After searching about I opened the inbound and outbound traffic for port 1433 on machine which is hosting IR and and outbound traffic for port 1433 on machine which is hosting the database but I am still getting the same error.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. As per azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-sql/database/adonet-v12-develop-direct-route-ports), if we are trying to connect to SQL database from within Azure cloud then we need to open communication to port range 11000-11999. We need to put this port range in network security list for outbound connections.